# Write keys, values to separate text files in folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, file-io

This is what I have so far:

```
for key,value in spee_dict:
    with open(key, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(value)
```

I get the following: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Probably this is because I have tens of thousands of words stored as values for each key. There are 893 keys. How can I get around this error?

Edit:

`Key` and `value` are all string.

Here are a few example of keys and values for `spee_dict`:

```
key      value
speech1  we should have gone to the other country a few years ago
speech2  our tax situation is completely fine and revenues are increasing
speech3  ladies and gentlemen, thank you for your attention
...
```

Basically, I want in a folder on my U:/ drive files like `speech1.txt`, `speech2.txt`, and `speech3.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries iterate on keys only.

Instead use

```
for key,value in spee_dict.items():
    with open(key, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(value)
```

In case you are on Python 2, it would make sense to use `iteritems` instead of `items` (i.e. it would not produce a list, but a generator)

```
for key,value in spee_dict.iteritems():
    with open(key, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(value)
```

Comment: Oh, right. for some reason, that doesn't write to my folder at directory: `U:/wordfolder`.. it just runs in the console

Comment: I believe OP wanted to write each value to its own text file with a filename of the corresponding key.

Comment: @pzp yes thank you, I just noticed now...... it's the usual [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) that bites

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning [`dict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) for Python 2.x.

Comment: Did I not make it clear I wanted to write each value to separate files?

Comment: @pzp done, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @GBR24 can you please show: 1) the type and format of the value of each dictionary item (you say `thousands of words stored as values for each key`, are they in a string/list/tuple); 2) exactly what you expect the program to output in each file